# Http 404 with different error message not identified in android UrlConnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, filenotfoundexception

As default the If the server throws a 404 then the android HTTPUrlConnection assumes FileNotFoundException.

But the server provided some error messages based on some custom server implementation

How capture this erorr message along with the FileNotFoundException

code

```
try{
    urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.connect();
    .....//get http status and message
    .....
    if(httpStatus >= 200 && httpStatus < 300){
         ins = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    }
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    Log.debug("Timeout in REST URL Connectivity");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    //it automatically comes here even before I try to parse the error
    Log.debug("Requested HTTP URL does not exists");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.debug("Error processing REST URL Connectivity IO Streams");
}
```

The server can return 404 in +ve use case also but with a different error message

```
   Code: 404
   Message: Request user does not exists
```

we could not sacrifice 404 error code, but the UrlConnection assumes that the URL itself does not exists based on the 404 error code.

Tested with Advanced REST Client in google chrome

Comment: You can always try to use `getErrorStream()` ... problem is that on some `HTTPUrlConnection` implementation I got `FileNotFoundException` even if in fact it is *500 internal server error* - in such cases I always try to "translate HTTPUrlConnection to apach http client"(or use some tools like fiddler2 to produce the same error) and check what is going on

Answer (score 1):

So I finally figured out the issue, Java reads the errors from JSON format. So if your JSON has status="error" then it will consider as Error and throw 404 or any other code. 
BUT you can retrieve your response if you use below code:

```
 if(httpStatus != 200 ){
         ins = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    }else{
      ins = urlConnection.getErrorStream();   // This is what will give you the data you are looking for
    }
```

Hope this helps. It helped me for Wordpress API in Android.

Answer (score 0):

HttpUrlConnection gives you a responseCode, in your case 404. Depending on the response code, you handle the inputstream or the errorstream. You can't read the inputstream if the responseCode is 404. 
Example:

```
            int httpResult = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (httpResult != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                Log.e(TAG, urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            }
```

Comment: but before reaching this code itself it goes to the try catch part, should I remove the try catch part?

Comment: if it doesn't get to the getResponseCode part, the url is invalid. Which means, you con't get a 404 like you said, you get no server at all. Have you tested your url with something like RestClient?

Comment: Yes, I have tested the server will return 404 in a +ve scenario also with a different message, but android assumes that the URL itself does not exists, and we could not sacrifice 404 error code

Comment: We ourself generate 404 in case the database select query for that username does not return any records

Comment: My question was, does the server log show the 404 error?